# polyserve is not working on local development environment

Tags: polymer

I am trying to launch polyserve on my local development environment but it is not working. thought it might be due to node.js updated node but still getting this error.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/polyserve/bin/polyserve:14
```

> const resolve = require('resolve'); ^^^^^ SyntaxError: Use of const in
>   strict mode.
>       at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:906:3

Answer (score 0):

According to my copy of polyserv, its package.json file says it needs the resolve module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve

Your error is that it can't find it.

Is polyserve installed locally - run npm install